# Indicating object (of varying shape and size) is selected on a touch interface

Tags: gui-design, mobile, interaction-design, touch-screen

What is the best way to indicate that an object (of varying shape and size) is currently selected in a touch interface such as the one below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you select an item?

If you are to just show the selected item, you can have a contrasting color in the background.
[image]

Assuming it is a shopping site, you would want to provide action icons like "Mark as favorite", "Add to cart", etcetera. In this case, no additional styling for the selected item would be required.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a selection outline with the height of the slider like this:

[image]

Since the item will never exceed the height of the slider, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Can have a variant too with the available JS frameworks and libraries, loading the content is taking negligible ms which helps us change the data in just a wink.

With the above speed, we can also go for another variation where more data can be shown to the user without much navigation between the pages and also by using the minimal space available between the slider height and width
 [image: a mock up]

The left and right nav buttons can be used to check the next and previous item. 
The User can also change to the default view by jus closing this view.